# Web Service working in visual studio but not in IIS 5.1

Tags: vb.net, web-services, byte

```
 Public Function storeFile(ByVal intSRID As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim engine As New AccessEngine.DBEngine
    Dim db As AccessEngine.Database = engine.OpenDatabase(DBFile)
    Dim CommandText As String = "SELECT * From ServiceReport " & _
    "WHERE(((ServiceReport.[ServiceID]) = " & intSRID & "))"

    Dim rs As AccessEngine.Recordset = db.OpenRecordset(CommandText, _
                                           AccessEngine.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset, _
                                           Nothing, _
                                           AccessEngine.LockTypeEnum.dbOptimistic)

    If Not rs.EOF Then 'Retrieve Attachments recordset 
        Dim rs2 As AccessEngine.Recordset2 = CType(rs.Fields("Attachment").Value, AccessEngine.Recordset2)
        'A Recordset2 object contains all of the same properties and methods as the 
        'Recordset object. The Recordset2 object contains a new property, ParentRecordset, 
        'that support multi-valued field types.

        If Not rs2.EOF Then
            'You can attach a maximum of two gigabytes of data '
            '(the maximum size for an Access database). Individual 
            'files cannot exceed 256 megabytes in size.

            Dim offsetbytes() As Byte

            Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
            Dim f2 As AccessEngine.Field2
            Do While Not rs2.EOF
                f2 = CType(rs2.Fields("FileData"), AccessEngine.Field2)
                'get offset to data
                offsetbytes = CType(f2.GetChunk(0, 4), Byte())
                offset = BitConverter.ToInt32(offsetbytes, 0)

                Dim headerBytes() As Byte = CType(f2.GetChunk(0, offset), Byte())
                allbytes = CType(f2.Value, Byte())

                Dim databytes(0 To (allbytes.Length - offset) - 1) As Byte
                Array.ConstrainedCopy(allbytes, offset, databytes, 0, allbytes.Length - offset)

                strFilename = CType(rs2.Fields("FileName").Value, String)

                bytesofdata = databytes

                'If numbytes is greater than the number of bytes in the field, 
                'GetChunk returns the actual number of remaining bytes in the field.
                'there appears to be a resource limit for GetChuck
                'so use Int16.MaxValue for bytes to return
                'ref:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194600.aspx

                'I will use a memory stream for temporary storage
                Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream
                Dim bw As New IO.BinaryWriter(ms)
                Do
                    Dim returnBytes() As Byte = CType(f2.GetChunk(offset, Int16.MaxValue), Byte())
                    If returnBytes IsNot Nothing Then
                        bw.Write(returnBytes)
                        offset = offset + returnBytes.Length
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop

                bw.Close() ' closes memory stream as well
                rs2.MoveNext() 'Get next attachment
            Loop
        End If 'rs2.NoMatch

    End If 'Not rs2.EOF
    db.Close()
    engine = Nothing

    Return bytesofdata

End Function
```

This is my code that is working in visual studios however when I run it in IIS I keep getting this error. 
This error always appears at this line of code : 
 
`Dim db As AccessEngine.Database = engine.OpenDatabase(DBFile)`
Error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file &#39;E:\OSDB.accdb&#39;. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngineClass.OpenDatabase(String Name, Object Options, Object ReadOnly, Object Connect)
       at CDBServiceR.storeFile(Int32 intSRID) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Code\CDBServiceR.vb:line 255
       at RetrieveServiceRData.storeFile(Int32 intSRID) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Code\RetrieveServiceRData.vb:line 49
```

I do not know how to get rid of this error.Please help.

My WebConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
<system.web><compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true"     targetFramework="4.0">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
<add assembly="ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/></assemblies></compilation>
<webServices>
<protocols>
<add name="HttpGet"/>
<add name="HttpPost"/>
</protocols>
</webServices>
<!--<identity impersonate="true" userName="NONLOCKDOWN\IUSR_NONLOCKDOWN" password="password"/>-->
</system.web>
<appSettings>
    <add key="DatabasePath" value="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\192.168.0.1\Share\tele.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>`
```

Comment: As the error says, the iis process most likely doesn't have permission to access that location. How to resolve that depends on your version and configuration of iis. If you google "Granting iis permissions" you should find what you need.

Comment: I have granted full control to ASPNET in the sharing & security options but I still get this error.

Comment: I don't think that user is correct for IIS. It does depend on the version you are using though, so let us know, or google it.

Comment: This should help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms526063(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I'm using 5.1, anyway I've read the document. But I don't know what I am suppose to do.

Comment: I was thinking of the paragraph "If anonymous access is allowed, the process identity is the account that is set in the AnonymousUserName metabase property. AnonymousUserName is configured to the IUSR_computer_name account by default." So try adding permissions for that user to your directory.

Comment: I have added fullcontrol for that account already but still get that error..

Answer (score 0):

try to include this line web.config

```
<webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

hope this helps !!! :)

Comment: Okay I have added my webconfig

Comment: sry i dont have the framework4.0 but still try this links below
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817267;
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596ff388-bc4c-472f-b029-aea2b0418bea.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

> All Com+ components have "Enforce Security" checked, and we added a
>   group called "users" and a user in that group called "NT
>   AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" that is used (This account is built
>   in). This is the setup we have with IIS6 and Win2K3 Server currently.

Comment: I am using IIS 5.1 and WinXP so how should I go abt changing the security?

Comment: please add the following to you web.config:
`<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <identity impersonate="true" userName="username" password="password"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>`